# Question Understanding Simple Algebra With Regards to Computational Complexity

Tags: algebra-precalculus, algorithms, computational-complexity, sorting

Initial Disclaimer: I decided not to post this on Stack Overflow as my problem lies with understanding the mathematics of this problem, but does not relate to theory at all.

I am studying Parallel Programming and am trying to understand the computation complexity of bitonic sort. Specifically when a hypercube interconnection network is used and there is a block of elements per processor. None of this matters for the problem at hand, but might give insight to others who are familiar with the subject.

I am confused by the following algebraic function

[image: computational complexity]

where *E* is defined as

*E* = $\frac{S}{p}$

Where *p* is a variable. My problem is that I can not figure out how they obtained the simplified expression for *E*.

For my question regarding the theory of this problem, please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20554504/understanding-computational-complexity-in-bitonic-sort)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is going to be a pain to type out the steps but when it comes to big-O math things are pretty darn simple.  The big-O hides almost everything.  So for us that means $\mathcal{O}(ab) = \mathcal{O}(a)\mathcal{O}(b)$, $\mathcal{O}(a/b) = \mathcal{O}(a)/\mathcal{O}(b)$, $\mathcal{O}(a - b) = \mathcal{O}(a) - \mathcal{O}(b)$, $\mathcal{O}(a + b) = \mathcal{O}(a) + \mathcal{O}(b)$, and $\mathcal{O}(n^k) = \mathcal{O}(n)^k$.

Factoring out the denominator and splitting the numerator we can safely start here:

$$ S = \frac{\mathcal{O}(n) \mathcal{O}(\log{n})}{\mathcal{O}(\frac{n}{p})[\mathcal{O}(\log{\frac{n}{p}}) + \mathcal{O}(\log^2{p})]} $$

Flipping the $n/p$ we can move to:

$$ S = \frac{\mathcal{O}(p) \mathcal{O}(\log{n})}{[\mathcal{O}(\log{\frac{n}{p}}) + \mathcal{O}(\log^2{p})]} $$

Then $\log{n/p} = \log{n} - \log{p}$ so:

$$ S = \frac{\mathcal{O}(p) \mathcal{O}(\log{n})}{\mathcal{O}(\log{n}) - \mathcal{O}(\log{p}) + \mathcal{O}(\log^2{p})} $$

Now divide by $p$ (which is $\mathcal{O}(p)$ in big-O notation) to switch over to $E$:

$$ E = \frac{S}{p} = \frac{\mathcal{O}(\log{n})}{\mathcal{O}(\log{n}) - \mathcal{O}(\log{p}) + \mathcal{O}(\log^2{p})} $$

Finally multiply by $1 = \frac{ \frac{1}{\mathcal{O}(\log{n})} }{ \frac{1}{\mathcal{O}(\log{n})} }$ to arrive at:

$$ E = \frac{S}{p} = \frac{1}{1 - \frac{\mathcal{O}(\log{p})}{\mathcal{O}(\log{n})} + \frac{\mathcal{O}(\log^2{p})}{\mathcal{O}(\log{n})}} $$

Combine the big-Os to see the exact output you desired.  Voila.

Comment: Well that seems to make sense. But I'm just wondering why does big-O math allow something like O(nlogn) to be split into O(n)O(logn), wouldn't it then just reduce to O(n) because n scales worse than log(n)? Sorry for this basic question, I completed the class and am even more rusty than I was previously...

Comment: Complexity analysis is trying to spot algorithmic differences that will matter even on super powerful machines from the future.  Multiplication has more clout than addition in that sense as computations get bigger.  Having to do an extra $\log{n}$ steps at every one of $n$ iterations is much more meaningful than doing 2 extra computations at each iteration or even $\log{n}$ extra steps of precomputation.

So $n$ is smaller than $n\log{n}$ and you would notice the difference on a huge problem.  But $n$ and $n + \log{n}$ are much harder to distinguish at large values of $n$.